# Analog Oscilloscope Flickering Signal Problem

Tags: analog, oscilloscope, measurement, trigger

I am using [BK Precision 2125C Dual Trace Oscilloscope (30 MHz)](https://www.bkprecision.com/products/oscilloscopes/2125C-30-mhz-delay-trace-analog-oscilloscope-with-probes.html#overview), which is analog. I'm trying to observe signal generated by the output of microprocessor. I'm seeing flickering signal (quickly moves left and right to the sides of scope) for which I know it's most probably not flickering like that in real "life" but that is most likely some scope's triggering issue. I'm almost sure that is the case since I observed normal square wave before this one and it also flickered like current one, at some trigger setting, but after re-setting trigger, there was no more flickering.

This flickering is **really** annoying when trying to observe little changes in the signal or read its period.

[Here](https://vimeo.com/532891476) is the video to measurement of flickering signal.

Just for reference, for this measurement, I'm using following setup:

- DC coupled input, CH1 (get same behavior with AC input coupling)
- coupling: norm (same behavior with "auto" or "TV-V" or "TV-H")
- source: CH1
- main mode (not mix or delay mode)
- voltage/div: 2V/div
- time base/div: 2ms/div

Regarding "trigger level" and "hold off", however I turn both knobs (literally any combination), I always get flickering or unsynchronized signal. Otherwise, I'm measuring at output of MCU (10k pull-up, UART transmission) with normal passive probe (in 1:1 internal divider rate).

Any ideas how should achieve the view of "standing-still" looking signal at the screen of scope?

Comment: Video link broken. Also, your signal better be periodic on an analog scope or it would flicker unless you use one-shot mode which analog scopes do not have. If you know enough to do so safely, hook it up to the AC mains (or a signal generator which is safer but also requires more $$$ to have) and see if it works. If it does, your signal isn't as steady as you think it is.

Comment: @DKNguyen Video link updated. Yeah, one shot not available here. So, no aperiodic signal measurement with this scope then... :(

Comment: On the other hand, it IS periodic... It repeats later on... I measured some other UART data transmission signal other day, and picture wasn't flickering at all, while this one flickers constantly at any trigger setting.

Comment: That looks more like jitter in your signal. How is the signal being generated by the MCU? In software? Or in hardware (peripheral), and if in software, is the code doing anything else? Especially tasks that might vary in time (loops, interrupts, etc).

Comment: @DKNguyen Yes, programming, so its most possible that code execution time varies between repetitions.

Comment: Make code that literally does nothing but loop count and toggle the pin and you shouldn't see jitter since the code runs the exact same every time (unless you have cache in your MCU)

Comment: @DKNguyen Just to clarify, many analog scopes have one-shot mode (e.g. Tektronix 453). Not all that useful because there is no storage capability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. Trace breaks at 0.2 divisions and restarts at almost 4.5 divisions.*

[image]

*Figure 2. Trace breaks at 0.2 divisions and restarts at almost  4.25 divisions.*

The problem isn't your 'scope - it's the signal. You have jitter of at least 0.2 / 4 = 5%.

You can usually confirm that the 'scope is stable using the 1 kHz test signal present on the front panel of most bench oscilloscopes.

Comment: So probably is, as @DKNguyen suggested, software problem? Yes, I'm programming my PIC microprocessor, where I program it. So I assume execution time of code must be changing between each repetition.

Comment: Yes, I would say that's likely.

Comment: @Keno I wouldn't call this a *software problem*. If your code is in a loop that checks some status flag, loop execution time can vary. Or if interupts occur, loop time can vary. If so,**Holdoff** won't change the display.

Comment: @glen_geek However I still think it is software problem. I'm trying to solve it as we speak, and also got some reduction in jittering while modifying code. Otherwise yes, my code checks for status flags and also does that via interrupts. I'm dealing with timer which is most probably the source of issue I'm trying to solve.

Comment: @keno Interrupts, branching code, cache, and loops that can run different number of iterations will all do it.

Comment: @DKNguyen Strangely though, just using loops and while in the program, doesn't causes this flickering. Implementing the timer, does. Anyway, I know this discussion is already getting out of scope of for the main question asked, but here if [link](https://www.microchip.com/forums/m1170093.aspx) to other forum, where I'm asking about software - for anyone interested in this matter. ;)

Comment: @Keno If your loops run the exact same way every time and nothing else is going on then I wouldn't expect flickering. If the timer is directly generating the signal I would also not expect flickering since it is being generated by ahrdware. But if you are using timer ISR code and the IC is doing other stuff then I would expect flickering due to variability in context changes when the interrupt fires.

Comment: @DKNguyen Actually, I even tried timer with polling and implementing delay without timer but using simple for() loop... got same results. However, source of this jittering is most definitely from timer/delay section

Answer (score 4):

It looks as if it characteristic of the signal rather than a problem with the scope. Even a digital scope would have a similar issue.

One way around this type of problem I use when developing MCU software is to exploit an unused GPIO on the MCU to act as a trigger for the scope.

Connect this additional GPIO to the other channel on the scope (or the external trigger if all channels are in use).

Within your code toggle this GPIO at the time you wish to trigger the scope.

As Transistor indicates in another answer the issue is probably caused by jitter in the signal - even that might be helped by issuing the trigger from within your code as as in some situations you may be able to arrange that the trigger has the same jitter as the signal you wish to observe and so cancels out. For example a GPIO trigger just before the character is sent out the UART should reduce the jitter dramatically rather than triggering from the previous character.